# How to avoid jQuery interfering with synthetic events of ReactJS?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, modal-dialog

It try to use a onClick (for instance) statement on a HTML element in a react class which is encapsulated in a jQuery driven modal dialog... It seems that jQuery , in modal mode, interfers with this syntetic event; example :

`<div class="modal" ref="dummy">
       <div onClick={(evt)=>alert("click")} />
    </div>`

with in componentDidMount

`$(this.refs.dummy).modal("show")`

modal being a jQuery plugin.

Any advice to make the syntehtic event working nevertheless?

Comment: What "interference" do you observe? Actually, the way you have used jQuery will interfere with the React v-dom because the modal plugin will make changes to the DOM nodes maintained by react. May I ask the need of mixing React with jQuery?

Comment: Yes, it does... My question is how to avoid this?
I need to mix react with jquery, because many widget libraries like bootstrap, semantic-ui and many more don't work without jquery... of course some like material-ui or react-bootstrap do without, but i need some components which are not provided with them.

Comment: Hmmm. I think you will need to cherry pick. Do you have a list of features you need for which you were dependent on jquery?